# Add middleware to 3rd party OWIN application

Tags: owin, katana, kestrel-http-server

One key ability with the old ASP.NET pipeline is the ability to add an HTTP Module to the pipeline via configuration. The advantage was the ability to add, say, redirects or filtering to a web application's pipeline where access to the application's source was not available.

My understanding of OWIN middleware - whether katana, kestrel or later - is that adding middleware and ordering is a compile/build time action.

Or is there some mechanism to insert a component at the beginning of the OWIN pipe for a web application via web.config type configuration?